# Laravel 4.2 static function doesn't return the correct values

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I have a laravel 4.2 application, but I want to show some stats...

So I want to show the most visitors etc...

I got this:

A class called `Stats` with this code inside of it:

```
public static function MostVisits()
    {
        return Tracker::selectRaw('count(*), date')->groupBy('date')->orderBy('count(*)', 'desc')->first();
    }
```

That works like a charm, when I execute the rendered code (`select count(*), date from`protrack`group by`date`order by`count(*)`desc limit 1`) in my SQL server, it gives the correct values.

Now I want to get everything:

`Stats::MostVisits()->count('*')` stand in my view, but gives me the count of ALL the records in that table...

But the date `date('d/m/Y', strtotime(Stats::MostVisits()->date))` does return the good part... so, how can I fix the count issue?

Comment: By using Stats::MostVisits()->count('*') you are explicitly telling the function to show count of ALL the records .                                                                      Create a variable $track=Tracker::selectRaw......... and return $track , then simply use MostVisits() to get everything.

Comment: So it is impossible to use the same function for the count as for the date?

Comment: Or do I need to return a variable instead of the query? Because the answer is kinda weird explained...

Comment: return the variable $track in the function.MostVisits()->date should still work ,try using MostVisits() for to get everything.To get specific query use MostVisits->query

Comment: I still don't get it, could you make an answer?

Answer (score 0):

By adding a foreach, I was be able to fix it.

So the controller method was now:

```
public static function CountMostVisits()
    {
        $json = Tracker::selectRaw('count(*)')->groupBy('date')->orderBy('count(*)', 'desc')/*->remember(1440)*/->first();
        $array = json_decode($json, true);
        return $array;
    }
```

As you can see, it returns json, wich needs to be decoded.

Then the view:

```
@foreach(Stats::CountMostVisits() as $stat)
            {{ $stat }}, op {{ date('d/m/Y', strtotime(Stats::MostVisits()->date)) }}.</p>
            @endforeach
```

That fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is because you have `->first()` on the end of your query.

By adding `->first()`, you have changed what your `MostVisits()` function returns.

Before the call to `first()`, you have an Eloquent query object. Calling `count()` on that would indeed change the query into a count query as expected.

However after calling `first()`, what you have is no longer an Eloquent query object. Instead it is an instance of `Tracker` containing the first record returned from the query. Calling `count()` on that will act as if you had called `Tracker::count()`, which will give you a count of all records.

The solution is to remove the `->first()` part from your `MostVisits` method, and move it to where you call `MostVisits()` instead.

Then you will be able to use `MostVisits` with `count()` as expected, or indeed any other query modifying methods.